# Odd mount behavior: Swap, ESP

Tags: grub2, mount, swap, fstab

I'm suddenly observing some odd mount behavior that is affecting both the swap and EFI system partitions, among others.  The system is Lubuntu 20.04.4 in a GRUB multi-boot configuration with Ubuntu Desktop (*i.e.*, GNOME3) 20.04.4 on another partition.  All partitions are on a single, unencrypted volume.

Initially, I got an error in launching VMware Workstation suggesting/insisting that swap be enabled.  This seemed odd because a swap partition is configured in fstab.  Sure enough,

```
swapon -s
```

returned no output and

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

returned no entries.  Doing

```
swapon -a
```

fixed this although the configuration did not persist through reboot.

The GRUB menu then did not appear as it had until then, so I checked /etc/default/grub, ran update-grub, and to be safe, grub-install, which returned:

```
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

This also seemed odd because the ESP also is mounted to /boot/efi in fstab.

Several other, but not all, partition mounts also failed.  The one that works contains /home.

Even more curiously, in the terminal emulator, I can recursively navigate to /boot/efi/EFI and its subdirectories.  After so doing, grub-install returns:

```
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

So, the system seems to be automounting, instead of mounting, partitions.

<s>WTF???</s> Any thoughts about why this might be occurring or how to fix it would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your issue; but the only differences I'm aware of between Ubuntu Desktop (using `ubiquity`) & Lubuntu (using `calamares`) is by default Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS installs a ESP for all systems (*regardless of whether or not it's required*), where `calamares` does not (*`calamares` only adds if required because machine was booted in uEFI mode*), and Ubuntu Desktop defaults to creating swap; Lubuntu 20.04 with `calamares` does not - but it'll use one if created or pre-exists.  They boot & operate the ~same; but sorry I don't understand your issue.

Comment: The issue is simple:  Suddenly the ESP and swap partitions are automounting instead of mounting.  The differences in installers is irrelevant because both systems are installed.  Both boot via GRUB (grub-efi, not grub-pc) and both mount the same ESP to /boot/efi.  Except that suddenly, Lubuntu doesn't-it automounts it (and apparently all other partitions) instead, which is the problem.

Comment: That doesn't make it any clearer; as Lubuntu is just a different desktop & user-level libraries/toolkits on the same Ubuntu 20.04 base.  Any differences between Ubuntu & Lubuntu on the base 20.04 system will be made by the ISO used to install which is *unspecified* (*but will be identical if 20.04.2 or later media was used to install Lubuntu as 20.04.2 & later has the same defaults as Ubuntu Desktop; it used the default of Ubuntu Server with regards kernel stack for 20.04.1 & 20.04 same as all flavors*)   As differences (between Ubuntu & Lubuntu) are user-level look for user caused changes

Comment: You won't understand until you apprehend that the question is about fstab and mount on a single system.  GUI distinctions bear on this as much as does the designated hitter rule.  If it helps, imagine it being headless server suddenly having the same storage issues (_i.e._, automounting instead of mounting partitions).  If you can't, then explain how stripping off the desktop manager and display server will affect the storage configuration and its behavior.  If you can't, then address the storage and mounting subsystems' operation and how that can be reconfigured to restore mount behavior.

Comment: You might want to post the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file and also check the kernel ring buffer (`sudo dmesg`) for messages about the mounting of filesystems, and post anything you find that might be relevant. I don't do much with automounting of filesystems, but you might want to check out [the relevant documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) for clues.